# Format date php get with getdate()

Tags: php

I am using the function `getdate()` to get the date, but I want the minutes, days or whatever to be printed out with two digits. I want to get a message like: `[day.month.year][hour:min:sec]`.

I've tried it like this:

```
$today = getdate();
$str = "[" . gmdate("d", $today[mday]) . "." . gmdate("m", $today[mon]) . "." . $today[year] . "][" .  gmdate("H", $today[hours]) . ":" . gmdate("i", $today[minutes]) . ":" . gmdate("s", $today[seconds]) . "]";
```

Instead of `gmdate` I've used `date`, but I get results like `[01.01.2013][00:00:59]`. If I check what `getdate()` returns, everything it's OK.

Is there a way I can format the date as I want and also to get the correct result?

Comment: I don't understand how `date()` doesn't do what you want

Comment: instead of using gmdate I used date; the same sintax; I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Or [`date_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)?

Comment: @PédeLeão, check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/185667

Comment: You don't need `date_create()` or `get_date()` just the one line of code given in the example by @CertaiN

Comment: @Stanciu, thanks for the answer you posted. These are better in answers rather than question-edits; I've moved it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
$str = date('[d.m.Y] [H:i:s]');
```

About format:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For now I've used the method I've found. In the future I will use this line:).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from the OP:

Matt Johnson, thank you for your help. I used date_format like this:

```
$today = getdate();
$date1 = date_create("" . $today[mday] . "." . $today[mon] . "." . $today[year] . "");
$date2 = date_create("" . $today[hours] . "." . $today[minutes] . "." . $today[seconds] . "");
$msg = "[" . date_format($date1, 'd.m.Y') . "][" .  date_format($date2, 'H:i:s') . "]";
```